# How to simultate Nao robot (Alebaran) in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to ask if there is a Nao simulation model for Gazebo.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35207/how-to-simultate-nao-robot-(alebaran)-in-gazebo?/) by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No change about Stefan's short answer "no" - at least for the time being. There is a Simulator SDK now available in the latest Nao software, so it might be possible to code something up.

Other than that we had some good results with Webots, the Nao basically works out of the box there and the API mostly works like a drop-in replacement for the real robot. You can see some results in the second part of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiIi2rSKWAU) (from 0:30). At that time there was no official ROS support but a Python node was easy to integrate. By now I think that Webots directly supports ROS.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2012-05-31**:
Wow, this work is beautiful! Thanks, it really helped me to get oriented, I'll be checking this deeply... :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I answered a similar question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33755/example-of-how-to-simulate-humanoid-biped-using/#33759). The short answer is "no". I know of Nao simulation for Webots, NaoSim and SimRobot, but none of those have a ROS interface AFAIK.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2012-05-29**:
Thank you very much, this is very helpful! :)

**Comment by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on 2012-11-30**:
Webots has ROS controller interface for a while.